# Swift ios 10 NavBar Item keeps growing

Tags: swift, animation, uinavigationbar

I have a navBar Controller connected to a UIView, I have a right bar button item that is a chevron.  I have programmatically created a search bar.  If you click the chevron about 20-100 times it keeps growing until it is off the screen.  I can see each time I click the chevron a slight bump in my search bar.  Since you can not place constraints on navBar and fixed Space bar button item does not work either.  Any suggestions on where to look or how to fix this?

```
func rotateChevron(animated: Bool = true) {
    let chevAnimate = animated ? 0.3 : 0.0
    let chevIsDown = messagePicker.frame.origin.y == self.view.frame.height - (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0)
    let rotation: CGFloat = chevIsDown ? 0.0 : 180.001
     UIView.animate(withDuration: chevAnimate, animations: {
        self.filterChevron.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotation.degreesToRadians)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I placed within the animation blocks a forced CGSize (w/h) and this seems to have solved the issue.  I also found that transform animation should not be used with frames because it moved the bounds of the image each time which is why the chevron was acting up.

```
func rotateChevron(animated: Bool = true) {
    let chevAnimate = animated ? 0.3 : 0.0
    let chevIsDown = messagePicker.frame.origin.y == self.view.frame.height - (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0)
    let rotation: CGFloat = chevIsDown ? 0.0 : 180.001
    filterChevron.customView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: 35, height: 30)
     UIView.animate(withDuration: chevAnimate, animations: {
        self.filterChevron.customView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotation.degreesToRadians)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```